# ASP DataGrid - Must declare the scalar variable "@LCompanyIDInt"

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, datagrid

I have an application I'm working on that have multiple grid views on panels, and those panels are selected by a dropdown list. The first one I'll put here works perfectly.

I have a second grid set up exactly the same (I think) as the first. I've changed variable names a bit, and added a few extra rows for stuff, but otherwise things are identical.

On this second grid, **I get an error that my first variable (LCompanyIDInt) is not declared**. I have no clue why it says that.

I've pasted both the working & non-working code below. Removed a lot of columns for space reasons, but it always bombs on the `LCompanyIDInt` issue on the 2nd grid, for either inserting or updating. Resetting or cancelling works fine.

**WORKING CODE:**

```
    <!-- Total Points Annuity -->       
        <asp:Panel ID="TPAnnuity_Panel" runat="server" visible="true">  
                <asp:GridView ID="TPAnnuity_GridView" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" Runat="server"
                    DataSourceID="TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="AnnuityTotalPointsID" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20">
                    <Columns>               
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" visible="False" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="AnnuityTotalPointsID" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AnnuityTotalPointsID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="EditAAnnuityTotalPointsID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AnnuityTotalPointsID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="EditACompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName" selectedValue='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="NewCompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewCompanyID" Display="Dynamic"  ForeColor="" ErrorMessage="You must enter a value. *" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>    

                        <etc I ran out of room> 

                       <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Reset"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource" Runat="server"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsAnnuity a left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblTotalPointsAnnuity](CompanyID, ProductName, IssueAges, PlanTypeName, AgentFYC, AgentRenewal, ContractPoints, BonusPoints, IncludeInSummary, IncludeInTopPicks, ActiveProduct) VALUES(@CompanyIDInt, @ProductNameText, @IssueAgesText, @PlanTypeNameText, @AgentFYCInt, @AgentRenewalInt, @ContractPointsDec, @BonusPointsInt, @IncludeInSummaryInt, @IncludeInTopPicksInt, @ActiveProductInt) "
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblTotalPointsAnnuity] Set CompanyID = @CompanyIDInt, ProductName = @ProductNameText, IssueAges = @IssueAgesText, PlanTypeName = @PlanTypeNameText, AgentFYC = @AgentFYCInt, AgentRenewal = @AgentRenewalInt, ContractPoints = @ContractPointsDec, BonusPoints = @BonusPointsInt, IncludeInSummary = @IncludeInSummaryInt, IncludeInTopPicks = @IncludeInTopPicksInt, ActiveProduct = @ActiveProductInt WHERE [AnnuityTotalPointsID] = @AnnuityTotalPointsIDInt">
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyIDInt" Type="Int32" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyIDInt" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:Panel>
<!-- END Total Points Annuity -->
```

**WORKING CODE BEHIND**

```
Sub TPAnnuity_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles TPAnnuity_GridView.RowCommand
    Dim TPAnnuity_searchStr As String = TPAnnuity_search_Text.Text

    If TPAnnuity_searchStr = "" Then
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsAnnuity a " & _
                                        " left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID " & _
                                        " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
    Else
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsAnnuity a " & _
                                        " left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID " & _
                                    "WHERE 1=1 "

        If TPAnnuity_search_dropdown.SelectedValue = "Company" Then
            TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND ci.CompanyName like '%" & TPAnnuity_search_Text.Text & "%' OR ci.CompanyCode like '%" & TPAnnuity_search_Text.Text & "%'"
        Else If TPAnnuity_search_dropdown.SelectedValue = "CompanyID" Then
            TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND ci.CompanyID = " & TPAnnuity_search_Text.Text
        Else
            TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND " & TPAnnuity_search_dropdown.SelectedValue & " like '%" & TPAnnuity_search_Text.Text & "%' "
        End If
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
    End If

    If e.CommandName = "Cancel" Then
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewProductName"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIssueAges"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewAgentFYC"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewContractPoints"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewBonusPoints"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Clear()

        Dim test1 As New Parameter("CompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test2 As New Parameter("ProductNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test3 As New Parameter("IssueAgesText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test4 As New Parameter("PlanTypeNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test5 As New Parameter("AgentFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test6 As New Parameter("AgentRenewalInt", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test7 As New Parameter("ContractPointsDec", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim test8 As New Parameter("BonusPointsInt", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim test9 As New Parameter("IncludeInSummaryInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim test10 As New Parameter("IncludeInTopPicksInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim test11 As New Parameter("ActiveProductInt", TypeCode.Byte)

        test1.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        test2.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewProductName"), TextBox).Text
        test3.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIssueAges"), TextBox).Text
        test4.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text
        test5.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewAgentFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        test6.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewAgentRenewal"), TextBox).Text
        test7.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewContractPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        test8.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewBonusPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        test9.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        test10.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        test11.DefaultValue = CType(TPAnnuity_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex

        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test1)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test2)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test3)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test4)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test5)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test6)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test7)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test8)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test9)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test10)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test11)

        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.Insert()
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Update" Then
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Clear()

        Dim param1 As New Parameter("CompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param2 As New Parameter("ProductNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param3 As New Parameter("IssueAgesText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param4 As New Parameter("PlanTypeNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param5 As New Parameter("AgentFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param6 As New Parameter("AgentRenewalInt", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param7 As New Parameter("ContractPointsDec", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim param8 As New Parameter("BonusPointsInt", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim param9 As New Parameter("IncludeInSummaryInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param10 As New Parameter("IncludeInTopPicksInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param11 As New Parameter("ActiveProductInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param12 As New Parameter("AnnuityTotalPointsIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)

        param1.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditACompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        param2.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAProductName"), TextBox).Text
        param3.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAIssueAges"), TextBox).Text
        param4.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text
        param5.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAAgentFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        param6.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAAgentRenewal"), TextBox).Text
        param7.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAContractPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        param8.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditABonusPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        param9.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param10.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param11.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param12.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditAAnnuityTotalPointsID"), Label).Text)

        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param1)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param2)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param3)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param4)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param5)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param6)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param7)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param8)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param9)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param10)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param11)
        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(param12)

        TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

**NOT WORKING CODE**

```
    <!-- Total Points Life -->      
        <asp:Panel ID="TPLife_Panel" runat="server" visible="false">
            <hr />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Search on </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="TPLife_search_dropdown" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Company" Value="Company"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Company ID" Value="CompanyID"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Product Name" Value="ProductName"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        <td> for </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TPLife_search_Text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="TPLife_search_Button" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="TPLife_search_Click" CssClass="buttonstyle" onmouseover="shade(this);" onmouseout="unshade(this);" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
                <asp:GridView ID="TPLife_GridView" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" Runat="server"
                    DataSourceID="TPLife_SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="LifeTotalPointsID" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20">
                    <Columns>               
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" visible="False" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="LifeTotalPointsID" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LifeTotalPointsID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="EditLLifeTotalPointsID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LifeTotalPointsID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="EditLCompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName" selectedValue='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="NewCompanyID" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ddlCompanyDS %>" DataValueField="CompanyID" DataTextField="CompanyName"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewCompanyID" Display="Dynamic"  ForeColor="" ErrorMessage="You must enter a value. *" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <etc I ran out of room>

                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Reset"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TPLife_SqlDataSource" Runat="server"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsLife a left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblTotalPointsAnnuity](CompanyID, ProductName, PlanTypeName, StandardAgtFYC, StandardFYCExcess, StandardRenewal, PreferredAgtFYC, PreferredFYCExcess, PreferredRenewal, ContractPoints, BonusPoints, IncludeInSummary, IncludeInTopPicks, ActiveProduct) VALUES(@LCompanyIDInt, @LProductNameText, @LPlanTypeNameText, @LStandardAgtFYCInt, @LStandardFYCExcessInt, @LStandardRenewalInt, @LPreferredAgtFYCInt, @LPreferredFYCExcessInt, @LPreferredRenewalInt, @LContractPointsDec, @LBonusPointsInt, @LIncludeInSummaryInt, @LIncludeInTopPicksInt, @LActiveProductInt) "
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblTotalPointsAnnuity] Set CompanyID = @LCompanyIDInt, ProductName = @LProductNameTest = @LProductNameText, IssueAges = @LIssueAgesText, PlanTypeName = @LPlanTypeNameText, StandardAgtFYC = @LStandardAgtFYCInt, StandardFYCExcess = @LStandardFYCExcessInt, StandardRenewal = @LStandardRenewalInt, PreferredAgtFYC = @LPreferredAgtFYCInt, PreferredFYCExcess = @LPreferredFYCExcessInt, PreferredRenewal = @LPreferredRenewalInt, ContractPoints = @LContractPointsDec, BonusPoints = @LBonusPointsInt, IncludeInSummary = @LIncludeInSummaryInt, IncludeInTopPicks = @LIncludeInTopPicksInt, ActiveProduct = @LActiveProductInt WHERE [LifeTotalPointsID] = @LLifeTotalPointsIDInt">
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LCompanyIDInt" Type="Int32" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LCompanyIDInt" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:Panel>
<!-- END Total Points Life -->
```

**NOT WORKING CODE BEHIND**

```
Sub TPLife_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles TPLife_GridView.RowCommand
    Dim TPLife_searchStr As String = TPLife_search_Text.Text

    If TPLife_searchStr = "" Then
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsLife a " & _
                                        " left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID " & _
                                        " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
    Else
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblTotalPointsLife a " & _
                                        " left outer join tblcompanyinfo ci on a.CompanyID = ci.CompanyID " & _
                                    "WHERE 1=1 "

        If TPLife_search_dropdown.SelectedValue = "Company" Then
            TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND ci.CompanyName like '%" & TPLife_search_Text.Text & "%' OR ci.CompanyCode like '%" & TPLife_search_Text.Text & "%'"
        Else If TPLife_search_dropdown.SelectedValue = "CompanyID" Then
            TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND ci.CompanyID = " & TPLife_search_Text.Text
        Else
            TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " AND " & TPLife_search_dropdown.SelectedValue & " like '%" & TPLife_search_Text.Text & "%' "
        End If
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.SelectCommand &= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CompanyName Is Null then 1 ELSE 0 END), CompanyName, ProductName "
    End If

    If e.CommandName = "Cancel" Then
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewProductName"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardRenewal"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredRenewal"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewContractPoints"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewBonusPoints"), TextBox).Text = ""
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
        CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Clear()

        Dim test1 As New Parameter("LCompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test2 As New Parameter("LProductNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test3 As New Parameter("LPlanTypeNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim test4 As New Parameter("LStandardAgtFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test5 As New Parameter("LStandardFYCExcessInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test6 As New Parameter("LStandardRenewalInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test7 As New Parameter("LPreferredAgtFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test8 As New Parameter("LPreferredFYCExcessInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test9 As New Parameter("LPreferredRenewalInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim test10 As New Parameter("LContractPointsDec", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim test11 As New Parameter("LBonusPointsInt", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim test12 As New Parameter("LIncludeInSummaryInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim test13 As New Parameter("LIncludeInTopPicksInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim test14 As New Parameter("LActiveProductInt", TypeCode.Byte)

        test1.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        test2.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewProductName"), TextBox).Text
        test3.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text
        test4.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        test5.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text)
        test6.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewStandardRenewal"), TextBox).Text)
        test7.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        test8.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text)
        test9.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewPreferredRenewal"), TextBox).Text)
        test10.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewContractPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        test11.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewBonusPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        test12.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        test13.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        test14.DefaultValue = CType(TPLife_GridView.FooterRow.FindControl("NewActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex

        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test1)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test2)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test3)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test4)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test5)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test6)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test7)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test8)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test9)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test10)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test11)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test12)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test13)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(test14)

        TPLife_SqlDataSource.Insert() ***FAILS ON THIS LINE***
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Update" Then
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters.Clear()

        Dim param1 As New Parameter("LCompanyIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param2 As New Parameter("LProductNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param3 As New Parameter("LPlanTypeNameText", TypeCode.String)
        Dim param4 As New Parameter("LStandardAgtFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param5 As New Parameter("LStandardFYCExcessInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param6 As New Parameter("LStandardRenewalInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param7 As New Parameter("LPreferredAgtFYCInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param8 As New Parameter("LPreferredFYCExcessInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param9 As New Parameter("LPreferredRenewalInt", TypeCode.Int32)
        Dim param10 As New Parameter("LContractPointsDec", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim param11 As New Parameter("LBonusPointsInt", TypeCode.Decimal)
        Dim param12 As New Parameter("LIncludeInSummaryInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim param13 As New Parameter("LIncludeInTopPicksInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim param14 As New Parameter("LActiveProductInt", TypeCode.Byte)
        Dim param15 As New Parameter("LLifeTotalPointsIDInt", TypeCode.Int32)

        param1.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLCompanyID"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
        param2.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLProductName"), TextBox).Text
        param3.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLPlanTypeName"), TextBox).Text
        param4.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLStandardAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        param5.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLStandardFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text)
        param6.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLStandardRenewal"), TextBox).Text)
        param7.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLPreferredAgtFYC"), TextBox).Text)
        param8.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLPreferredFYCExcess"), TextBox).Text)
        param9.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLPreferredRenewal"), TextBox).Text)
        param10.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLContractPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        param11.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLBonusPoints"), TextBox).Text)
        param12.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLIncludeInSummary"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param13.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLIncludeInTopPicks"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param14.DefaultValue = CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLActiveProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedIndex
        param15.DefaultValue = Utils.NumOrNull(CType(e.CommandSource.FindControl("EditLLifeTotalPointsID"), Label).Text)

        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param1)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param2)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param3)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param4)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param5)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param6)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param7)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param8)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param9)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param10)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param11)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param12)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param13)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param14)
        TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(param15)

        TPLife_SqlDataSource.Update() ***FAILS ON THIS LINE***
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried comparing both front & back codes, and can't see the issue. I've tried making the 2nd panel visible by default, and it doesn't change anything. The reset function works fine on the 2nd grid, but the insert and update commands don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change these lines

```
TPAnnuity_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(testN)
```

to

```
TPLife_SqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(testN)
```

**EDIT**

You forgot to change the table name of the `asp:SqlDataSource` `INSERT` and  `UPDATE` commands from `tblTotalPointsAnnuity` to `tblTotalPointsLife`

Comment: Well, that was a pretty glaring mistake, but sadly it didn't help.

Comment: Actually, this brought up an additional issue. The update still is doing the same thing, but now the insert says `Invalid column name 'StandardAgtFYC'.` for that row & 5 others. I've verified the spelling is correct.

Comment: Progress! Insert now works. Update does not. But this is good. Thank you.

Comment: So, the update error still be the same?

Comment: `UPDATE [tblTotalPointsLife] set ... ProductName = @LProductNameTest = @LProductNameText` This was the final issue. Thanks for helping me chunk away at the bits & pieces though.